# Center text vertically and same containers height with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to do the following design using **flexbox**. I can't use **table** or **dispay:table** due to programming requirements

[image]

I can't center the text vertically and maintain the same height in all containers:

https://jsfiddle.net/kurtko/2fq6kn6m/

I'm trying to use to items:

```
align-self:center;
```

Or to container:

```
align-items:center;
```

But I lose the same height in all containers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` `align-items: center` `justify-content: center` on `.one` `.small` `.medium`

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.one,
.small,
.medium {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.one {
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.one {
  width: 39%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.two {
  width: 29%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.three {
  width: 40%;
}
.medium {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  height: 200px;
}
.small {
  background-color: #c0b55a;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

  <div class="one">
    Top
  </div>

  <div class="two">
    <div class="medium">Center</div>
    <div class="medium">Center</div>
  </div>

  <div class="three">
    <div class="small">Center</div>
    <div class="small">Center</div>
    <div class="small">Center</div>
    <div class="small">Center</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can add `.one { align-items: flex-start;}` https://jsfiddle.net/2fq6kn6m/5/ or you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/2fq6kn6m/6/

Answer (score 0):

Check the **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/heshamElghndour/2fq6kn6m/3/)** 
I just update on first div what you missed. 
added to `one`:

```
.one{
 align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```